# Translation morphism of Algebraic Groups .

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

My question is about a point on page 18 of J.S.Milne's  "Algebraic Groups- The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field."  and specifically about the fact that the translation map induced on an algebraic group by a rational point is an isomorphism.
To be more precise the statement is :

Let $(G,m)$ be an algebraic group over k. For each $a∈G(k)$, there is a translation map
$l_a:G\stackrel{\sim}{\to}\{a\}\times G\to G$ where the second map is the group multiplication $m$ of the group scheme G.

For $a,b\in G(k)$
$l_a\circ l_b=l_{ab}$.

From this "composition law " argument and the identity element property of the distinguished rational point the fact that the translation is an isomorphism follows easily.

While this is very clear intuitively, I struggle to show it using the categorical  definition of group schemes,  i.e the commutativity of the diagrams representing associativity, identity element and inversion.

I would really appreciate any help !

Comment: Just to be clear: You struggle to show $l_a \circ l_b = l_{ab}$?

Comment: Yes . I apologise if its obvious

Comment: No it's fine. I just wasn't sure I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$
Associativity is expressed as the commutativity of the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G \times G \times G @>{m \times \id}>> G \times G\\
@V\id \times mVV @VVmV \\
G \times G @>{m}>> G
\end{CD}$$
Now if you restrict to $\{a\}\times \{b\} \times G$, you get
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{a\} \times \{b\} \times G @>{m \times \id}>> \{ab\} \times G\\
@V\id \times mVV @VVmV \\
\{a\} \times G @>{m}>> G
\end{CD}$$
Identifying $G \cong \{a\}\times\{b\}\times G$ as before, the "upper way" in this diagram is $m \circ (m \times \id) = l_{ab}$, whereas the "lower way" is $m \circ (\id \times m) = l_a \circ l_b$. By commutativity you get $$l_{ab} = l_a \circ l_b.$$

Comment: Ok, Its clear now. Thanks!